# how to integrate hudson and selenium-rc

Tags: selenium, hudson, selenium-rc, testng

I am using Selenium RC(Java) with TestNg. I run the script using TestNG. Now i want to integrate selenium with Hudson. So that whenever Hudson deploy the build into test server Dev team wants to perform Regression Testing using Hudson.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use ant task to start/stop selenium before/after executing your test. Another way is starting server from code if required. You can use [ISFW](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#testing-frameworks) where server started by framework if required.